# Firebase v9 - Get a Referentiated Document Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand why I'm not finding this documentation anywhere.

But I have a collection called `users` in my Firebase Firestore project. Inside `users` there are three collections: `companies`, `policies` and `stores`.

In the collection `policies` I have one `store` field and one `company` field that are references to one of that user's `store` or `company`.

Ok so as far as now is fine. But now, I'm performing the next query:

```
const subcollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'users', 'S3casIyXxdddEAaa1YJL6UjBXLy2', 'policies'));
```

And the response is the next one:
[image]

But now... how can I get the `company` and `store` nested documents? How can I "populate" them in order to see their information and access their fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `company` and `store` fields are of type `DocumentReference`.

In that case you can get a `DocumentSnapshot` of each of them by calling `getDoc()` with the `DocumentReference`:

```
subcollectionSnapshot.docs.forEach((policyDoc) => {
  const companyRef = policyDoc.data()["company"];
  const companyDoc = await getDoc(companyRef);
  const storeRef = policyDoc.data()["store"];
  const storeDoc = await getDoc(storeRef);
  ...
})
```

If you have multiple policy documents, you will need to do this for each of them. There is no concept of a server-side join in Firestore (nor in most other NoSQL databases).